# Problema simple de geometria con Unity y C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, script, unity

Necesito detectar cuando una pelota cruza una línea (raycast + renderer de línea, por ahora) que estará entre dos puntos (como un arco de gol de fútbol) ... pero estos puntos se moverán alrededor de la pantalla ... ¿Cómo puedo detectar eso? que el balón cruzó la línea?

Cualquier solución que me abra la mente será de ayuda para mí

Gracias !!!!!

Mi version actual :
Pensé poner un flag para cuando el raycast toca la pelota, y si dsp deja de tocarlo y el flag está true, lo cuenta como gol... pero podría suceder que toque la linea, rebote con uno de los palos y deje de tocar el línea ... en este caso lo contaría como meta sin haber cruzado la línea ... lo cual estaria mal !

Comment: Hola Nogerad, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Esta pregunta es muy amplia. Has de mostrar tu codigo actual intentado solucionar lo que pides y los errores o problemas concretos que te impiden conseguirlo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: Esto es matematicas, antes de intentar programar busca la formula de una recta y la formula que indica si un circulo corta la recta en algun punto, cuando lo tengas solo tendras que traducirlo. Se que estas formulas existen porque lo dimos en segundo de BUP

Comment: Veelicus : Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero no es tan sencillo como verificar que un punto corta una recta, ya que ahi digamos que estaria detectando lo mismo que la colision con la linea de gol.. lo que necesito saber es : Cuando cruzó la linea de meta, no cuando esta sobre la linea de meta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Crearia esos dos objetos, El padre deberia estar posicionado en el centro de la pelota, Pero sin ser hijo de la pelota, lo haces mover via script, Y el hijo deberia estar en el centro del padre, y tambien debe tener un pequeño collider, asi que la posicion del hijo seria:

`X: Radio de la pelota + tamaño del collider
 Y: 0
 Z: 0`

(Si tu juego es 3D, cambia el X por el Z)

El script del padre debe hacer que rote con la velocidad del rigidbody de la pelota, lo haria con algo asi:

`transform.rotation=Quaternion.SetLookRotation(VelocidadDeLaPelota);`

(Talvez sea la velocidad negativa, Prueba de las dos formas)

(Si tu juego es 3D o 2D, puede variar, pero es algo asi)

Y asi el objeto hijo pasara justo despues de que pase la pelota, Y puedes detectar cuando el raycast colisione con este y es porque ya pasó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]